# Is it possible to attach event handlers to controls in the page using AwesomiumDotNet?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm using Awesomium.NET and I dont understand why this code works on Chrome and It doesn't when using the Awesomium.NET (The WinForms Sample).

This is my page.

[image: my page]

When I click the button using Chrome I see the alert as expected, but if I use Awesomium.NET, nothing happens....
Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
If you run into a similar issue, just upgrade to awesomium 1.7 RC3 and the problem goes away. At least It worked for me ;)